# SQL Server View Access Speed Versus Writing View to Table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a SQL Server 2008 DB that has a set of views that are accessed by a program.  Our goal is to optimize the access speed of the program (which pulls in data on a user request), to minimize end-user impact.

Right now we are writing all of our views to tables, and passing those mappings to the application (we found the application performed better reading from tables as opposed to views).  We are soon going to implement indexes (still need to discuss with the application vendor what indexes will speed up their import), but for now we're trying to figure out the best way to optimize the import.

The plan currently is to write the views to tables, add the proper indexes and then run a (select *) statement to force them into memory.  My question is whether A) writing them to tables is necessary once we have the indices and the select * and B) what are some methods that we are missing?

Edited to clarify question goal.

Comment: Not clear and critical.  Exactly what is: regularly pulls data from a linked DB and manipulates it into a set of views?

Comment: Do you mean you have a **View** that is selecting from a **Linked Server**? Are you planning on adding the indexes to the Views or the Tables? Your 3rd paragraph implies both. I don't think you can index views that used Linked Servers. If you do index a View, then it is essentially a Table in which case you wouldn't need another Table. And while `SELECT *` will read all pages into memory, it doesn't guarantee that they will stay there. Nor does `SELECT *` read the indexes. Were you going to write a query per index to load them all? How did `SELECT *` ever come up as a performance optimization?

Comment: @srutzky [SELECT *](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816130/forcing-sql-server-to-pre-cache-entire-database-into-memory) For indexes, the LS Tables are written into the DB.

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I follow

Select into implies you are dropping the table and let select into create
You are probably better off with a truncate
If it is a FK then you need to delete but they tend to be smaller
And then just do an insert into
This way you also don't need to drop and recreate views

If you can take the hit you are better off taking a tablock hit the whole table

If the linked is slow then insert into some local staging tables
From the staging table load the production table

I totally don't get why you would materialize a view into table.
If you have performance issue with a view then first optimize the view.
What is going on in the view that is slow?

Comment: Speed tests indicated that the application imported data faster from tables than from views... For the Linked server, all of the tables are written into local staging tables.

Comment: So that does not mean views are optimized.  If it is just about view versus materialized table then why all the linked DB stuff.  Answer is only as good as the question.  FOCUS